# Assertion failed on anonymous Javascript function

Tags: javascript, marketo

*Javascript is a mystery to me.*

Why do I get "Assertion failed on anonymous function" errors with the function below?

It seems pretty straightforward; it checks for the existence of a domain in a text field in a Marketo contact form and allows/disallows the form validation.

The function is supposed to work with a 3rd party script (a Marketo external library) and the on-page function

`MktoForms2.loadForm("http://app-sjn.marketo.com", "023-GTK-123", 4567);`

which shows a contact form (which is the reason a JSFiddle won't work), so this may be difficult to fix with the code I can show here.

The main script is at http://app-sjn.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.js I obviously can't change anything there. But is there anything obvious in the function below? Or how it interacts with the main script? Is `(function ()` the issue?

```
(function (){
  var invalidDomains = ["@gmail.","@yahoo.","@hotmail.","@live.","@aol.","@outlook."];

  MktoForms2.whenReady(function (form){
    form.onValidate(function(){
      var email = form.vals().Email;
      if(email){
        if(!isEmailGood(email)) {
          form.submittable(false);
          var emailElem = form.getFormElem().find("#Email");
          form.showErrorMessage("Must be Business email.", emailElem);
        }else{
          form.submittable(true);
        }
      }
    });
  });

  function isEmailGood(email) {
    for(var i=0; i < invalidDomains.length; i++) {
      var domain = invalidDomains[i];
      if (email.indexOf(domain) != -1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

})();
```

And this is the HTML that the script targets on document ready:

```
<input style="width: 150px;"
class="mktoField mktoEmailField mktoHasWidth mktoRequired mktoValid" maxlength="255"
name="Email" id="Email" type="email">
```

**Update 10/31/16**

The "Assertion failed" error appears to be a canard, according to Bergi, and now I guess the issue must be with the function above and how it works with the main script.

Comment: Please show us the stacktrace of the exception, it doesn't seem to come from your code.

Comment: That make sense; I toggled stach trace in Firebug and nothing shows. Do I need to add console.trace() to the script above?

Comment: No, `console.trace` won't lead you anywhere. You need to find the place where the assertion is made.

Comment: OK, there are a bunch of assertations in the main marketo script forms2.js, linked in the question above. But that may not be much help, as I can't change them, but maybe this script can be adjusted.

Comment: None of those `assert` calls seem to test your function, but rather some kind of browser compatibility. Is the exception not caught, or did you just come across these while debugging? What exactly changes when you don't execute your script?

Comment: on which line you get ther error? is it the first one? Also could you add to the question the portion of html where the email field is defined?

Comment: Sounds like we're getting somewhere; I added the HTML that is rendered by the on page script, whose input is supposed to be modified by the script above. Nothing changes with or without the above script; the form submit works. And, now I see that the Assertion failed errors seem to be only in Safari, not Firefox/Firebug. And there are line #'s for the errors, but they don't correspond to anything as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is interesting. The script works. BUT, the way it is written and the way it works with main `forms2.js` Marketo script led me to believe it didn't work.

That's because the Javascript "showErrorMessage" shows the text warning "Must be Business email" *only* when the form validation is evoked with the "submit" button for the complete form, and only when text is entered in several more required fields below the #Email field.

So this script does not solely error check the #Email field; that's what I assumed. And even when I happened to add text in one more required field below #Email in testing, it doesn't throw the `showErrorMessage`.

The form validation only works when 1) all required fields are filled in (there is one non-required field after all those, too, that of course isn't validated since it is not required) and 2) there is an attempt to submit before there are checks on #Email.

So, it turned out to be something of a combination of a user breaking anything that could be broken, and what I think is not very user intuitive form validation.